# Partial summation of character $\chi \pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters, sieve-theory

In Ch. 8 (p. 142) of the **Opera de Cribro (Friedlander, Iwaniec)** it is written:

> To this end we apply the sieve to remove from each $p$ in a set $\mathcal{P}$ residue classes which are not squares modulo $p$. Since we are looking for an upper bound the sifting range $\mathcal{P}$ does not need to include every prime. Therefore, we choose $\mathcal{P}$ to be a large finite set which does not contain a few inconvenient primes, and we denote by $P$ the product of all primes in $\mathcal{P}$. Since the sieve weights are supported on divisors of $P$ we do not need to display the condition $d \mid P$ in various summations to follow.
>
> In our case, the number of residue classes to be removed is given by
>       $$\omega(p)=\frac{1}{2}(p-1),\qquad\text{for every $p \mid P$}.$$
>   We have
>   $$S^\square(\mathcal{A})\leq S^+(\mathcal{A},\Omega),$$
>   where $S^+(\mathcal{A},\Omega)$ is given by (8.3). Our goal is to find good weights $ρ_d$ (these will be almost optimal) and to evaluate $S^+(A,\Omega)$ asymptotically for these weights.
>
> We find that, for a non-principal character $\chi \pmod{p}$,
>   $$\Omega_p(\chi)=\sum_{\nu\in\Omega_p}\chi(\nu)=-\omega(p)=-\frac12(p-1)$$
>   if $\chi = \chi_p$ is real and $\Omega_p(\chi) = 0$ if $\chi$ is complex.

My question is the assertion in last line above. I think for the real case it uses the fact that real characters come from Jacobi symbol and the fact that the summation of a character (real or complex) over the $p-1$ residues is zero, i.e. $\sum_{\nu=1}^{p-1}\chi(\nu)=0$, but the assertion in complex case in the last line above is not clear to me?

Comment: It seems that $\Omega_p$ contains the quadratic non-residues modulo $p$. Then, with a primitive root $g$ modulo $p$ we have $$\sum_{\nu \in \Omega_p} \chi(\nu) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} \chi(g)^{2k+1}\,.$$ Note that $\chi(g)^2 \neq 1$ for non-real $\chi$ and use the sum formula for a geometric sum.